# How to use android phone as a login key to your PC

Tags: linux, password

Is there a way to setup a Linux box to enable authentication by inserting correct android phone with correct software in it to allow user to login?

So when there is a login prompt shown user should be able to just connect her/his android and voila; user has logged in.

Comment: This old SuperUser question covers some similar ground and there's a few suggestions that this could be done easiest with Bluetooth, but no actual apps that help http://superuser.com/questions/21364/how-do-i-detect-when-a-user-is-sitting-in-the-chair-in-front-of-a-computer

Answer (score 2):

This probably would work similarly to an [RSA Security Token](http://www.rsa.com/press_release.aspx?id=11206).

Comment: it doesn't seem to have released? or is it?

Comment: @Power-Inside: I think they're referring to this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rsa.securidapp